# How to figure out what formula corresponds to a given package in homebrew?

Tags: install, homebrew, package-management

I am trying to install 'Parallel Patterns Library' for c++. The package is generally abbreviated 'ppl'. As I did

```
brew home ppl
```

I figured that the formula 'ppl' is associated with ['Parma Polyhedra Library'](http://bugseng.com/products/ppl) and not 'Parallel Patterns Library'. How can I find out what formula is associated with 'Parallel Patterns Library' (if any)?

---

Eventually more generally, I'd welcome advice on how to install 'Parallel Patterns Library' if there is no homebrew formula for it.

Answer (score 1):

`brew desc` should search among both formula names and descriptions, and is now [included in `brew`](https://github.com/telemachus/homebrew-desc). The site [Search Brew](http://searchbrew.com) also uses this. However, both seem to cover only the default repository, as a quick test on my machine fails to pick up packages in `homebrew/python`.

In the specific case of the Parallel Patterns Library, I'm not sure that the entire 'ppl' is actually available on Mac. Microsoft has made a subset of it cross-platform as ['pplx'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj987780.aspx), but otherwise I have no good news.